# Bet365 website is not working

Tags: windows, server, web

I'm trying to add `bet365.com` UI to my desktop application, but the site is not show up!

I tried: 
- IE, Chrome, Firefox

Im running *Windows Server 2012*. 
I tried `HMA VPN` to change my IP location, changed DNS, nothing works.

Any help please!

Browsers screenshots below.

[IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giApb.png)

[And Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pk32h.png)

Updated:

- I have tried Bet365Mobile version->same issue
- With Chrome, allow 'Load Unsafe Scripts' -> same issue, nothing showup

Comment: welcome, and refer tour to learn how and what kind of question should be asked.

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to provide HTTPS before your URL.
that is  src="https://" if your program has a URL that is calling the website. Prefix the Https before that

You can search for mixed content directly in your source code. Search for http:// in your source and look for tags that include HTTP URL attributes. Specifically, look for tags listed in the mixed content types & security threats . Note that having http:// in the href attribute of anchor tags () is often not a mixed content issue

refer to this  link
[Mixed content prevention](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/fixing-mixed-content)

follow this [link](https://pearsonnacommunity.force.com/support/s/article/ka6d00000019KVGAA2/How-to-display-mixed-content-with-Google-Chrome-Internet-Explorer-or-Firefox-1408394589290) if your using the website as a user

Comment: does it load if you open it from outside the application?

Comment: it doesn't load inside app and all outside browsers

Comment: Take a look into your .js file, make sure that you are using the right ajax URL (//bet365.com/, instead of http://bet365.com/handler

Comment: Also your chrome error message says the endpoint as "http://localhost." Your requesting an Https page. change it to "https://localhost" in any of your configuration file

Comment: man, im trying to open Bet365 website as a User, their website is not my code, how can i edit source code??

Comment: im just regular user trying to use Bet365.com